# Why is it impossible to branch-off a real function smoothly and boundedly? (modified)

Tags: analysis, derivatives

It is well-known that given two real functions $f,g$ infinitely differentiable and with bounded derivatives $|f^{(n)}(x)| \le M$ and $|g^{(n)}(x)| \le M$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ and all $n=0,1,2\ldots,$ such that $f^{(n)}(a) =  g^{(n)}(a) $ for all $n=0,1,2\ldots$ , then from Taylor's theorem it follows that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.
Thinking graphically, this means that we cannot smoothly branch-off from $f$ at any point, without derivatives becoming unbounded, which means that we cannot 'glue' perfectly well two different curves at a single point without the derivatives of one of them running to infinity.
I'm trying to find an algebraic or geometric explanation of this amazing fact, that the two functions must be equal everywhere. So my question is: Is there an explanation that does not involve their explicit expansion into power-series?

Comment: The conditions aren't strong enough. Since $f$ and $g$ are twice differentiable (and more), $f'$ and $g'$ will achieve a maximum on $[a, b]$. So, pick any analytic function, and any other infinitely differentiable function with the same Taylor series, and all of the above conditions will be satisfied.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ In any case, I think that what you asserting is impossible isn't. Your assertion in your first sentence is certainly false.

Comment: @Theo Bendit: Suppose f(x)=0 for all x. So how do i branch-off at x=0 smoothly with bounded derivative?

Comment: [Here's one way.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#An_example_function)

Comment: Maybe you're referring to the case when there existing some $M$ such that for all $n$, $|f^{(n)}(x)| \le M$ and $|g^{(n)}(x)| \le M$, where $M$ is independent of $n$?

Comment: @Theo Bendit: yes, for all n.  I will modify the question. Thank you.

Comment: If all the derivatives are uniformly bounded then the function is analytic, thus globally determined by local behavior. Just the first one alone will not be sufficient.